# Web API. Generic Controller with attribute routing

Tags: generics, asp.net-web-api, routes, owin, attributerouting

**The problem**

When I create a method with a route on the actual controller, say:
*"api/country/something"...*

When I perform the above request, my code gets executed & data gets returned.

But when I try call my route on the base controller. E.G: *"api/country/code/123"*

I get a 404 error.

**Question**

Any idea on how to implement generic routes whilst making use of attribute routing?

**Specific Controller**

```
 [RoutePrefix("Country")]
 public class CountryController : MasterDataControllerBase<Country, CountryDto>
 {
   public CountryController(
             IGenericRepository<Country> repository, 
             IMappingService mapper, 
             ISecurityService security) : base(repository, mapper, security)
            {
            }
 }
```

**Base**

```
public class MasterDataControllerBase<TEntity, TEntityDto> : ControllerBase
    where TEntity : class, ICodedEntity, new()
    where TEntityDto : class, new()
{
    private readonly IMappingService mapper;

    private readonly IGenericRepository<TEntity> repository;

    private readonly ISecurityService security;

    public MasterDataControllerBase(IGenericRepository<TEntity> repository, IMappingService mapper, ISecurityService security)
    {
        this.security = security;
        this.mapper = mapper;
        this.repository = repository;
    }

    [Route("code/{code}")]
    public TEntityDto Get(string code)
    {
        this.security.Enforce(AccessRight.CanAccessMasterData);

        var result = this.repository.FindOne(o => o.Code == code);

        return this.mapper.Map<TEntity, TEntityDto>(result);
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19989023/net-webapi-attribute-routing-and-inheritance/24969829#24969829

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Attribute routing in Web API doesn't support inheritance of the `Route` attribute. You can see this indicated by `Inherited = false` if you view the definition of the `RouteAttribute` class...

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method, Inherited = false, AllowMultiple = true)]
public sealed class RouteAttribute : Attribute, IDirectRouteFactory, IHttpRouteInfoProvider
{ ...
```

This explains why you're getting the 404, as the `Route` attribute effectively disappears.

Since the attribute is not inheritable and the class is sealed, I don't know if there's a way to do this with the attribute routing infrastructure that comes out of the box.

Update: A member of the Web API team explains it was a design decision that it's not inherited... https://stackoverflow.com/a/19989344/3199781

Comment: Since Web API 2.2 it is possible to inherit route attributes. See http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/releases/whats-new-in-aspnet-web-api-22