# MVC Attribute Routes & Route Inheritance

Tags: asp.net-mvc, routes, asp.net-mvc-5

I am trying to get attribute routing in MVC5 to let me inherit the routes from a base controller. Example:

```
public abstract class BaseController: Controller
{
    [Route("")]
    public virtual ActionResult Index()

    [Route("edit/{id}")]
    public virtual ActionResult Edit(TKey id)

    //etc
}

[RoutePrefix("people")]
public class PersonController : BaseController
{
    //etc
}
```

Then obviously I should have `/people` for the Index page, `/people/edit/1` for the Edit page etc. However, it seems like this is not supported or I just don't know what I'm doing. Is there a way to get this working the way I want?

Comment: Route attributes cannot be inherited.

See:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19989023/net-webapi-attribute-routing-and-inheritance

Comment: +1 for the link. Thanks, @esmoore68. Bad luck; let's hope they allow such a scenario in a future version.

Comment: @esmoore68, add your comment as an answer and I will mark it as the correct answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to this: [.NET WebAPI Attribute Routing and inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19989023/net-webapi-attribute-routing-and-inheritance), route attribute cannot be inherited. Apparently, MVC 5.2 will have support for doing this through IDirectRouteProvider.