# Using WebApi RoutePrefix attribute on a base controller

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-web-api-routing

I would like all controllers which inherit from `AdminBaseApiController` to be prefixed with 'admin'.

This works fine of course:

```
[RoutePrefix("admin")]
public class ToggleController : AdminBaseApiController
{
    [Route("toggle")]
    public HttpResponseMessage Get()
    {
    }
}
```

However when I move the `RoutePrefix("admin")` out of the `ToggleController` and into the `AdminBaseApiController` (where I want it) - The route fails and I get a 404.

Am I looking at this all wrong? Thanks in advance!

Comment: [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19989023/net-webapi-attribute-routing-and-inheritance) pretty much sums it up.  And the documentation about halfway down [this page](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/releases/whats-new-in-aspnet-web-api-22)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Support for inheritance has been enabled in Web API 2.2 release...You can take a look at an example in the following Release Notes:

http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/releases/whats-new-in-aspnet-web-api-22#ARI