# RouteArea and "Multiple controller types were found that match the URL" error

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, routes

let's say I have this master controller in my MVC app:

```
[RouteArea("Blog")]
public class PageController : BaseAppController
{
}

[RouteArea]
// Called on mydomain/Blog
// and also called on mydomain/
public class BaseAppController : Controller
{
    [Route]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return Content("this is the index file form the main controller");
    }
}
```

as it is expected, I will get that `Index` action on `mydomain/Blog`, but for some reason I get it also in my `/` which it conflicts with another view I have from another controller.
I do not have any default set up for any of my roots:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
    routes.LowercaseUrls = true;
    routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes(new CustomDirectRouteProvider());

}
```

any idea what's the problem?

Comment: What is CustomDirectRouteProvider?

Comment: @AlexArt. that's there to enable Controller inheritance. check it out here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19989023/net-webapi-attribute-routing-and-inheritance

Comment: @Hooman - According to the comments below that answer, many people are unable to get it working. Also, the answer is for **WebAPI**, not for **MVC**.

Comment: @NightOwl888 thanks, but that wasn't the case. check out the answer please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it came up I need to make the base class as `abstract` since it's in top of the hierarchy, so there wouldn't be any other instance of it accessible by other views.
so in above example:

```
[RouteArea("Blog")]
public class PageController : BaseAppController
{
}

[RouteArea]
// is going to be called just on mydomain/Blog and not on mydomain/
public abstract class BaseAppController : Controller
{
    [Route]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return Content("this is the index file form the main controller");
    }
}
```