# C# Web API 2.2 Route Inheritance

Tags: c#, inheritance, asp.net-web-api, routes

I have followed all the documentation I can find, but for some reason this is not working.

I was unable to find a solution from:
[.NET WebAPI Attribute Routing and inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19989023/net-webapi-attribute-routing-and-inheritance)

WebApiConfig

```
 public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        // Web API configuration and services

        // Web API routes
        //config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes(new CustomDirectRouteProvider());

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
public class CustomDirectRouteProvider : DefaultDirectRouteProvider
{
    protected override IReadOnlyList<IDirectRouteFactory> GetActionRouteFactories(HttpActionDescriptor actionDescriptor)
    {
        return actionDescriptor.GetCustomAttributes<IDirectRouteFactory>(inherit: true);
    }
}
```

BaseApiController

```
public class BaseApiController : ApiController
{
    //Some stuff i require on the base controller
}
```

CrudApiController

```
public abstract class CrudController<TDto, TAdd, TEdit, TLookup> : BaseApiController
    where TDto : BaseDto, new()
    where TAdd : BaseModel
    where TEdit : BaseModel
    where TLookup : BaseModel
{
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("{guid:guid}")]
    public virtual TAdd Get(Guid guid)
    {
        TDto dto = DataService.Get<TDto>(guid);
        return dto.Map<TAdd>();
    }
 }
```

UsersController

```
[RoutePrefix("api/users")]
public class UsersController : CrudController<UserDto, AddUserModel, EditUserModel, UserGridModel>
{}
```

packages.config

```
<package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi" version="5.2.3" targetFramework="net45" />
```

When I run the following, I always get:

message:

> No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'http://localhost/accu/api/users/33ba2e96-06cb-43de-a661-1115039f630f?_=1446037569376'."

messageDetail:

> No action was found on the controller 'Users' that matches the name '33ba2e96-06cb-43de-a661-1115039f630f'."

Unless I put,

```
[Route("{guid:guid}")]
public override AddUserModel Get(Guid guid)
{
    return base.Get(guid);
}
```

on the `UsersController`.

Comment: There is no working solution on that question, even though its marked as answered.

Comment: I see. Perhaps you could make it more clear, which snippet is from the linked duplicate. But now I see it, so I'll vote for reopening.